# How to make exoplayer's ClippingMediaSource more precise?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I try to play short piece of mp3 audio (44100 samples rate) with exoPlayer using it's ClippingMediaSource but it cuts the start of the piece for about 250 milliseconds, it's too much, is it possible to make it more precise?

I start exoplayer like this:

```
dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "com.example.player"));
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri);
ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
ClippingMediaSource clip = new ClippingMediaSource(audioSource, 7_225_000, 8_175_000);
exoPlayer.prepare(clip);
```

Comment: The developers of ExoPlayer answered that this is the issue of the MP3 format and it won't be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the exoplayer documentation, there are the two methods

1. ClippingMediaSource(MediaSource MediaSource, long startPosition, long endPositionUs)

Creates a new clipping source that wraps the specified source and provides samples between the specified start and end position.

2. ClippingMediaSource(MediaSource mediaSource, long startPositionUs, long endPositionUs, boolean enableInitialDiscontinuity)

try the second method with false or adjust startPosition and endPosition.
For more check, this [clipping documentation](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/source/ClippingMediaSource.html#ClippingMediaSource-com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource-long-long-boolean-) of ExoPlayer. Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the second method and the result was the same (not accurate enough).

Comment: if you just want to play the audio file you can use exoPlayer.prepare(audiosource ) if it didn't work then change your audiosourece declaration like this 
mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null); 
but if you want to play from the specific start and end point then you can adjust the start time.

Comment: I'm not sure about how much of the piece is cut by ClippingMediaSource, is this value always the same and how to mesure it, I can estimate only by ears..

Comment: hi @AndreyKo after reading bugs relate to clipping in exoplayer I found that second method only works if the start time is keyframe  check [this](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3001)

Comment: Thanks for your help but as I commented to my own topic the issue is not related to the ClippingMediaSource but to the MP3 format itself which cannot be indexed properly. It seems that the longer the track is the less precise you can clip it. But for other audio format such as AAC everything works as expected. I also tried my own solution based on MediaExtractor instead of using ExoPlayer to play piece of MP3 audio and the issue persisted.